# Can't figure out why setting wx.SpinCtrl "value=" to variable isn't working

Tags: wxpython

So I have a main menu set up with a button that opens a separate options window. It works fine, except for the fact that I can't find a way to keep the value of my spincontrol widget after the menu is closed. This is my current code:

```
 self.spincontrol = wx.SpinCtrl(self.optionmenupanel, value=OtherClass.variable, size=(60,-1))
```

On closure of the options menu, this runs:

```
OtherClass.variable = self.spincontrol.GetValue()
str(OtherClass.variable)
```

The thing is, I get the error:

```
TypeError: String or Unicode type required
```

The variable should be a string, I even used `str()` to make sure. So why is this still happening, and is there a different or better way to do this?

Comment: Give it an initial value `initial=0` for example and see if that stops the error, it may be that it has no value. A spinctrl really should be an integer

Comment: Is the options menu in another class? If so you might need to `return` the value of self.spincontrol.GetValue()

Comment: The spincontrol is in the options menu class - and giving an initial value doesn't change the issue @Rolf of Saxony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume your problem stems from the fact that `SpinCtrl` can accept either `str`/`unicode` and `int` (accepting text makes sense for the `TextCtrl` part, `int` makes sense for the "spin" part. However, `SpinCtrl.GetValue()` will always return an `int`, so it would make sense to treat `OtherClass.variable` always as `int`.

So best would be to use:

```
    val = OtherClass.variable
    self.spinctrl = ...(..., value="", ...) # value only can be ``str`` !
    self.spinctrl.SetValue(val) # will accept ``str`` and ``int``

    self.spinctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_SPINCTRL, self.on_spin)

def on_spin(self, evt):
    res = self.spin.GetValue()
    assert isinstance(res, int)
    OtherClass.variable = res
```

Comment: This was successful! Can you explain what that `on_spin` function does?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but a) it is bound to ``EVT_SPINCTRL`` (gets called by event system when ``SpinCtrl`` changes), b1) reads out the value from the control, b2) (optional) makes sure it is int, b3) assigns the value to ``OtherClass`` (which I presume is what you want to change, because why would you want a SpinCtrl in the first place?)